# problem with C# printing from a serial buffer

Tags: c#

i have a program in C#. and i want to print out what the program gets from serial.

```
class Serial
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
        using (SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM2", 6200))
        {
            sp.Open();
            //read directly
            sp.Read(buffer, 0, (int)buffer.Length);
            //read using a Stream
            sp.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)buffer.Length);

            Console.WriteLine(buffer); 

        }
    }
}
```

The program writes out System.byte[] and then quits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to what SLaks said, this would be the fix:

```
string bufferText = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
Console.WriteLine(bufferText);
```

Comment: This uses the system's ANSI code page, which is probably not the best choice.

Comment: True, using Encoding.ASCII is probably better.

Comment: Or Unicode or UTF8, depending on the device at the other end of the serial port.

Answer (score 3):

Your `buffer` variable is a `byte` array.

`Console.WriteLine` does not have special handling for byte arrays, so it just prints the result of the `ToString()` function.

If you want to print meaningful content, you will need to create a string from the byte array that contains your content.

You probably want to call [`Convert.ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f9a8s97.aspx), [`Encoding.ASCII.GetString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc.aspx), or [`BitConverter.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a733s97.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Because `byte[].ToString()` does not nicely print each element of the array, it prints the name of the type.  Loop through it and build a string first.